# You have sent too many requests. Try again soon error in shopify

Tags: shopify

I have one shopify store [Sprintshopping](https://www.sprintshopping.com) to sell my products . And i Have more than 12,00,000 products in my store .

Every thing was fine But From Today am facing some problem ..

If click most of the link its giving error message "**You have sent too many requests. Try again soon."**

Example screenshot  : [Click Here](http://screencast.com/t/YZXDcbtqM)

Example URL : [click Here](https://www.sprintshopping.com/collections/womens-clothing)

I have no idea Why this error is coming . i spoke to **shopify guru** they are telling this problem because of your **theme** .

can any one explain me why this problem is coming .

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked out the official shopify documentation? https://help.shopify.com/api/guides/api-call-limit

Comment: Would help if I can replicate the error. Which link is causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This error is not coming from the API but from the Shopify load balancer instead.
It means that with every click you make in your store, you are generating extra requests to Shopify server. It may be indeed the problem of your theme as it may try to fetch some additional information all the time.

Another option is to just switch the pricing package in Shopify and see what happens.

Comment: the shopify never mentioned any where regarding a  API call or anything http://screencast.com/t/oXNf9TfntqT